# Global Access to a Singleton's Data

Tags: c++, singleton, assets, allegro5

So I'm making a graphical application (game) that I want to utilize an Asset Manager. For this class I decided to use a Singleton Design. So in my main.cpp I would load something like...

```
ASSET_MANAGER.LoadImage("res/graphics/background.png", "background");
```

Here is the implication of the macros/methods used in the line above. This is sort of a mashup of code that I have to make things simpler to look at instead of pasting a few hundred lines of code into here.

assetmanager.h

```
#define ASSET_MANAGER AssetManager::GetAssetManager()
#define DEBUG

class AssetManager {
public:
static AssetManager &GetAssetManager();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Purpose: Load a new image for the game to use. This function will store an
//          instance of the asset in memory (in a hash map corresponding with
//          the data type provided.
//
// param file: The location on disk of the asset
// param key: The string you use to receive this asset (defaults to the path str)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool LoadImage(const char *file, const char *key = "");

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Purpose: Returns the image
//
// param key: The string used to store the asset in memory
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *GetImage(const char *key);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Purpose: Destroys an asset that is presumably no longer needed by the game.
//          This function is good for performance so that you don't use more
//          RAM than you need to.
//
// param key: The string you use to receive this asset (defaults to the path str)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void DiscardImage(const char *key);
private:
    AssetManager();

    ~AssetManager();

    std::map<const char *, std::shared_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP>> _ImageMap;
}
```

assetmanager.cpp

```
AssetManager &AssetManager::GetAssetManager() {
    static AssetManager instance;
    return instance;
}

bool AssetManager::LoadImage(const char *file, const char *key) {
    key = key == "" ? file : key;
    std::shared_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP> x(al_load_bitmap(file), al_destroy_bitmap);
    if (!x) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load %s\n", file);
        return false;
    }
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("DEBUG: Loaded %s\n", key); //debug
#endif // DEBUG
    _ImageMap.insert(std::pair<const char *, std::shared_ptr<ALLEGRO_BITMAP>>(key, x));
    return true;
}

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *AssetManager::GetImage(const char *key) {
    return _ImageMap.find(key) != _ImageMap.end() ? _ImageMap.at(key).get() : nullptr;
}

void AssetManager::DiscardImage(const char *key) {
    _ImageMap.erase(key);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("DEBUG: Discarded %s\n", key); //debug
#endif // DEBUG
}
```

This class only works from the class I initialized the asset manager in while I expected it to work anywhere that I called ASSET_MANAGER. It compiles fine, it only crashes when I try to use the manager in a different class and pass it into an allegro function because it returns something that is null instead of the proper allegro data types. What don't I understand about this?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in what way it doesn't work elsewhere? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it only load kittens?

Comment: On a side note, unless you exclusive use string literals and are careful, `const char*` as a map key is mostly useless as you're mapping pointers, not strings. Prefer `std::string`.

Comment: +molbdnilo It compiles fine, but in classes where ASSET_MANAGER wasn't defined, it doesn't get the data. The GetImage() function just returns null instead of the data that I loaded in. This causes allegro to crash the application because it can't render null.

Comment: That's almost certainly because you're mapping pointers.

Comment: +molbdnilo So the maps should not have pointers in them? What is the problem with that?

Comment: The problem is that you're using the location of a string as the key instead of its contents. For instance, if you `LoadImage("foo"...)` then `char[] foo = "foo"; ... GetImage(foo, ...)` will fail.

Comment: Another problem is that your default `key` is `""`, which is "truthy". So you're storing everything using the same key (i.e. a pointer to the empty string) unless you specify one.

Comment: it will be helpful if you post the code that cause crash.

Comment: The default key is the file name, but ill try changing the `const char*` to `std::string`.

Comment: +Lidong Guo the crash is from allegro saying the assets i'm trying to use are null.

Comment: +molbdnilo you should post the "unless you exclusive use string literals and are careful, const char* as a map key is mostly useless as you're mapping pointers, not strings. Prefer std::string" thing as the answer so I can hit the check mark button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Char* in the map stores the location and not the data which makes the program think it's null.